# can I make radial labels on highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to generate a donuts highchart, everything is running good but I can't find the way to make the labels rotate in a radial way.
I've tried:

```
dataLabels: 
{
    rotate = 'auto'
}
```

but no lucky
nothing is documented on Highcharts API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Is it possible or I'm just dreaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this option is not supported, but you can try to use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter and useHTML, then use your own css styles to prepare correct rotation.